# React-Motion: Not Rendering TransitionSpring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-native, reactjs

My entire component is attached here:

https://gist.github.com/j42/392e63b275e1209ac269

The relevant render method from the component is below, for convenience:

```
render() {

    let className = this.state.active ? 'active hidden-xs' : 'hidden-xs';

    return (
        <div id="git-flow" className={className}>
            <div className="beanstalk-container">
                <div className="beanstalk"></div>
                <ul className="events">

                    <TransitionSpring
                        defaultValue={this.getDefaults()}
                        endValue={this.getEndValues()}>

                        {key => {
                            this.state.people.map(function(person, i) {

                                let deployFailed = (Math.round(Math.random()*1) <= 0.4),
                                    headline     = (deployFailed) ? 'PUSH BLOCKED' : 'PUSHED TO PRODUCTION',
                                    className    = (deployFailed) ? 'status negative' : 'status positive',
                                    icon         = (deployFailed) ? 'ion-android-close' : 'ion-android-checkmark-circle';

                                return (<li key={i}
                                            className="person"
                                            style={{
                                                top: `-100px`,
                                                opacity: `1`
                                            }}>
                                            <div className={className}>
                                                <i className={icon}></i>
                                                <div className="label-text">
                                                    <h4>{headline}</h4>
                                                    <h5><strong>Dec 15th, 2015</strong> &mdash; 5:00PM</h5>
                                                </div>
                                                <ul className="notifications">
                                                    <li className="notification">
                                                        <i className="ion-email-unread"></i>
                                                        <span>Group Leader Notified</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="image">
                                                <img src={person.picture.medium} className="img-responsive" />
                                            </div>
                                        </li>);

                            });
                        }}

                    </TransitionSpring>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

**The Problem:**

This code runs without any errors, but only renders so far as `ul.events`.  Within that is `<noscript data-reactid=".2.0.1.0"></noscript>` which leads me to believe React is encountering an error with the JS, and thus silently ignoring the bracketed content.

Everything looks normal to me though... I'm still a bit new to react, so is there something basic I'm overlooking?  I just want to have a list of avatars that essentially `fadeInDown` within a `TransitionSpring` (so components can be added and removed)...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI right now I'm not worried about the animation part (extracting vals) -- I overwrote those with hardcodes for now because I'm just trying to get the bloody thing to render :)

Answer (score 0):

use React Native [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#content).
It's designed to work with React Native.